# Angular error in render - component not found

Tags: angular

I am very very new to Angular and getting a error during loading the webpage. There is no error during compiling. Please help.

The error in console is

Can't bind to 'form' since it isn't a known property of 'app-form'

My html (document-edit.component.html)

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
   <app-form [form]="form"></app-form>
</div>
```

My ts code. The path is definitely valid otherwise VS code highlights it in the IDE itself (document-edit.component.ts)

```
import { myForm } from 'src/app/shared/forms/my-document';
```

in the declaration of ts (document-edit.component.ts)

```
form: FormGroup = myForm( this.fb );
```

in my-document (my-document.ts)

```
import { Validators, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';

export const myForm = ( fb: FormBuilder) => {
    return fb.group({
        name: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
    });
 }
```

Could someone please help as to what could be the problem?

My Files

```
C:\Code\MyProject\src\SPA\src\app\shared\forms\my-document.ts
C:\Code\MyProject\src\SPA\src\app\views\projects\project\document-edit\document-edit.component.html
C:\Code\MyProject\src\SPA\src\app\views\projects\project\document-edit\document-edit.component.ts
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app.module.ts` just add `import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';` . In addition, you have to import `FormGroup` in your `app.component.ts` and in the template change `[Form]` into `[FormGroup]`.

Here is a simple sample for you:

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [],
  exports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component.ts**

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder } from  '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  
  contactForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.createContactForm();
  }

  createContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      fullName: [''],  
      email: [''],
      message: ['']
    });
  }

  onSubmit() {
      console.log('Your form data : ', this.contactForm.value );
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="contactForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <input type = "text" name = "fullName" placeholder = "Your full name" formControlName="fullName" >
  <br/>
  
  <input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "Your email" formControlName="email" >
  <br/>
  
  <textarea name = "message" placeholder = "Your message" formControlName="message" ></textarea>
  <br/>
  <input type = "submit" value = "Send">
</form>
```

Comment: It is exactly as you have mentioned

Comment: Ok . Then you have to import `FormGroup` in your `app.ts` and in the templete chane it to `[FormGroup]`. I updated my answer with a simple sample for you. Check it out aand let me know if still there is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported ReactiveFormsModule in your module.ts

```
import { ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
```

Comment: Yes its there but still same problem

Answer (score 0):

This error is throwing because the binding of [form] is the syntax of a input to a component, which You have to add the code in `app-form.component.ts`

`import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';`

`@Input() form:FormGroup;`

To declare in your app-form component

`<app-form [formGroup]="form"></app-form>`

Then it will not throw an error .

Comment: Adding Input() gives an error in VS Code 'cannot find name Input'

Comment: Unfortunately still the same

Comment: Please provide the file names for the code that you have put in question

Comment: In the question

Comment: Sorry - In the question now

Comment: Added one more change.   formGroup at last line of code